# Make it harder to edit/roll back a moderator's edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderation

When a moderator edits a question, it shouldn't be reversible by a regular user. For instance, a mod sees a flag about a 1-rep user ranting in their post, and edits the post to get rid of it. If that 1-rep user returns and re-edits to insert the rant again, that mod won't know unless someone else re-flags.

I would suggest that it require a substantial amount of rep to change a post once a moderator has edited it. Possibly even restrict this ability to 10k users.

**Edit**:  Perhaps, rather than blocking completely, any edits thereafter by low rep users (the level of rep being in question), those edits just go into the edit queue for review and approval by users with the required rep.

Comment: Seems like a good idea in theory, but then the bullets start flying. Would you then become responsible for all edits to the question? If another user asks for clarification, the original poster could not provide it.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a timed lock if the user wrote something that suggested they were going to be abusive? I guess that would have its own problems... Still, it seems very risky to block most people from editing because, for example, Marc fixed a typo when he was answering someone's question.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Good point, one that will probably torpedo this request.  Thanks.  I guess 10k is too high.  Maybe drop it down to the 2k region.

Comment: @TimStone: Timed block, possibly.  Or the edit would just go into the proposed edit queue until a user with enough rep can ensure it isn't ranty.

Comment: Dude, mods are like monkeys with guns. That isn't awesome nor infallible.

Comment: Isn't that why we have the locking feature?

Comment: @Chichiray: Huh?  Monkeys with guns are both awesome and (at least from their perspective) infallible.

Comment: @Null lock every single edit *just in case the user rolls it back?*  Not feasible.

Comment: I vote for the checkbox that says "Notify me of additional edits to this post." This could also be useful when posting new questions and answers, with a "Notify me of any edits to my post."

Comment: The potential unintended consequences seem disastrous.  For instance, [you edit a lot of titles](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will?tab=activity&sort=revisions).  Just by virtue of you touching the titles, the bodies would no longer see improvement by the original askers.

Comment: @Farray: Um, I think we've addressed this in the evolution of answers and comments.  Specifically, the edit goes into the edit queue so that any user with the minimum rep would be able to accept.

Comment: RE your edit, isn't that exactly how all edits work for low rep users? Which already seems like a suitable solution to me...

Comment: @BenBrocka: Uh, not on their own posts.

Comment: True, but...why would you block edits on one's own post, ever? One should *always* be able to edit their own post, no one knows as much about the problem prompting the question as the asker.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Again, it is supposed to be a level of block inbetween "user can revert mod edits" and "mod locks post forever and ever".  So 1) low rep user (<2k?) rants 2) mod edits 3) low rep user tries to revert 4) edit goes into the edit queue 5) >2k users see rant in the edit queue and deny the edit.

Comment: @Wont Saw that but disagree with the concept.  Any solution that potentially removes/degrades the original asker's access* to his/her own question devalues the utility of asking questions on the site.  (*-Of course, accounts can be banned - but that is in reaction to bad behavior.  Removing access for something as simple as writing a bad title sounds way too harsh.)

Comment: @Farray: Eh. We block new(er) users from doing lots of things.  What's one or less?

Comment: @michael omg wtf lol brb going to revert your edit in a few mintues

Answer (score 14):

Meh.

Moderators can *lock* posts. That's pretty much the ultimate "don't touch mah edits!" If you don't feel you need to lock, then act like a normal user and let your edit stand or fall according to the whims of the OP.

Of course, locking also implicitly closes the question, which isn't always desirable... But if there's a real need for locking edits on open questions, I think we need to support that as an explicit moderator option - not implicit protection on every edit a moderator happens to make.

Comment: I'm for that as well.  I don't want to lock a post for X hours because I *think* the user might roll it back.  Also, the locks say when they are lifted, so anyone planning on rolling back will just wait.  Having something between "user clowns mod by rolling back edits" and "fascist mods ripped my flesh" would be nice.

Comment: Well, if a user is determined to subvert a moderator's actions, they can pretty much always manage to do so - or at least, chew up unacceptable amounts of moderator time trying. So really, you want to be sending them increasingly strong messages to the effect of "don't do that" until they either get it, or you end up suspending them for not getting it.

Answer (score 3):

One possible middle-ground would be to disable *only* the option to *roll back* the mod edit, but leave other editing possible. This would mean that in order for a user to reinsert inappropriate content, they would have to retype it all instead of just getting one-click satisfaction. That may be enough of a deterrent to keep crap from getting reinserted, but it would still let them edit in additional information as needed.

Comment: Copy-paste from the original...only slightly more work than clicking "roll back"

Comment: Many users are unaware of the roll back feature, and submit an edit with copy-pasted text already.  This is a small deterrent if it's a deterrent at all.