# low-rep user rolls back a good edit

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, signatures

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841188/why-would-twitter-have-deprecated-the-use-of-delete-as-a-request-method-in-their), the asker initially included a signature.  This was later edited out by a high-rep user.  Then, the asker edited the signature back in.

The asker's rep is low enough that he/she probably doesn't know that signatures are frowned on (and didn't take the hint when it was edited out).

Possible courses of action in the future:

1. flag for moderator attention
2. edit post
3. edit post + add comment pointing to FAQ
4. whine on meta (check)

Recommendations?

Comment: A *somewhat-related* discussion that may interest you: [Make it harder to roll back a moderator edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117240/make-it-harder-to-edit-roll-back-a-moderators-edit)

Comment: `edit post + add comment pointing to FAQ` That. After you posted this, another user removed the signature again, so I went ahead and left the comment myself.

Comment: But, if you notice a repeating behaviour, flag, flag, flag!

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117240/make-it-harder-to-edit-roll-back-a-moderators-edit).  Good idea not to go for the sarcastic humor angle in your question.

Comment: @jadarnel27: lol, didn't see you already pimped my question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please just flag this behaviour for the mods to deal with, there's no point getting into an edit war over it. We can put a lock on the question to prevent it happening again should the OP not get the message.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's from a mod.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say edit it again, and post a comment. Flagging seems way too much at this point, especially if you can make him realize that there's a rule on the signatures.

Comment: Agreed. Edit again, post a nice comment, if you're in the mood add some links to Meta discussion on the topic.

Comment: Certainly do flag if the behavior continues after the situation has been explained to the user however.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, the person asking a question fundamentally "owns" that question. While I appreciate the rule against un-needed cruft on posts in SE, I have to say that I'm conflicted about making it more difficult to roll back posts when you own a question.

I can't help thinking that there is potential for someone to edit a question in good faith and change the meaning of it - at that point it should not be difficult for the person who asked the question to say "no, that's not what I meant at all" and roll things back. And I don't see how you can tell the intention behind a rollback. (And what if someone makes a substantial edit to a post, mistakenly edits something important to the question and also removes salutations from the post... what should happen then?).

I think we should be looking to explain the rules to new people and give them the chance to do things the right way, not impose them.

Comment: `don't see how you can tell the intention behind a rollback` In this case, it's quite obvious from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8841188/revisions), the OP didn't rollback, but did [another edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8841188/3) just adding his twitter handle. I think your answer is more relevant to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117240/make-it-harder-to-edit-roll-back-a-moderators-edit)

Comment: "At the end of the day, the person asking a question fundamentally "owns" that question." Not really. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post

Comment: *sigh* - you go and try and explain that to a new user, @Piskvor'sSemifiniteMonkeys and do let me know how you get on. They may well not own it in the sense you mean, but they own the truth of the question - if they say "I have a problem with a bit of code doing "*X*" in my environment" or whatever, while all of us might be more qualified than them to know what ought to happen, they're the expert on what they're actually seeing happen.

Comment: @Rob Moir: Fair point. (I didn't realize you meant something else than actually "owning" the question.)